# Rule of Naming Variables for Boolean

Tags: javascript

how should I name for variables on type Boolean like 'Mom is away from keyboard'.

```
var momIsAwayFromKeyboard = mom.isAwayFromKeyborad;
```

is correct??

Comment: What do you mean? your variable declaration is fine if mom is an object.But it is quite big though

Comment: is mom an object here? if not then why  not go like `isMomAwayFromKeyboard`

Comment: if mom is an object then as Krishna said? your variable looks fine( `mom.isAwayFromKeyboard`)

Comment: Though it is not a strict convention, ideally the boolean variable or properties should start from { is }. i.e. isMomAwayFromKeyboard.

Comment: variable names should be short and easy to understand. For this instance you can use isMomAFK ,           ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: mom is an object here.
I want to know the suitable variable name for substituting 'mom.isAwayFromKeyborad'.
momIsAwayFromKeyboard, isMomArayFromKeyboard, or else.

Comment: @MehulVaghela more like they start with a verb that matches the thing `isAway` would use "is", but if you need a flag for "somebody who has money in account" `isWithMoney` sounds awkward and you'd use `hasMoney`. If a flag is if somebody is able to pay, then `canPay` is more appropriate. Then you can also drop the verb if it's fairly obvious `isCorrect` works but `correct` is also not hard to grasp that it's a boolean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually, you start with 'is'.

I think a good, short, descriptive name could be:

`isMomAFK`
or
`isMomAway`

Think of it as a true/false question: 'Is Mom away from keyboard?'

Answer (score 1):

You could use a destructuring assignment:

```
let {isAwayFromKeyboard} = mom;
```

In this way you need only to write the variable name once and there will no difference b/w key and variable name.

```js
let mom = {
  isAwayFromKeyborad:true
}

let {isAwayFromKeyborad} = mom;

console.log(isAwayFromKeyborad)
```

Comment: Great answer but you misspelt `isAwayFromKeyborad`.